# NHibernate - Select a different value if the first value is null

Tags: nhibernate

In the query below, we are looking at the Claim record and want to return the Account.Name that is associated with that record if it exists (the Account object here can be null).  If that value is null, we want to return the Claim.BillingAdjuster.Account.Name value instead.  Here's our original query without this check:

```
           var q = this.Session
                .QueryOver<Claim>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == claimName.ToString())
                .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Account, () => claimCompany)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.BillingAdjuster, () => billingAdjuster)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Account, () => billingAdjusterCompany)
                .SelectList(sl => sl
                    .Select(x => x.ClaimNumber).WithAlias(() => pi.ClaimNumber)
                    .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => pi.ClaimName)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjuster.FirstName).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterFirstName)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjuster.LastName).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterLastName)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjuster.AccountingCustomerId).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterAccountingCustomerId)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjuster.SalesForceCustomerId).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterSalesForceCustomerId)
                    *.Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.Name).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterCompanyName)*
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.BillingStreet).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAddress)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.BillingCity).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingCity)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.BillingState).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingState)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.BillingPostalCode).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingPostalCode)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.Fax).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingFax)
                    .Select(() => billingAdjusterCompany.Phone).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingPhone)
                    .Select(() => policyHolder.FirstName).WithAlias(() => pi.PolicyholderFirstName)
                    .Select(() => policyHolder.LastName).WithAlias(() => pi.PolicyHolderLastName)
                    )
                    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<PlacementInfo>())
                    .SingleOrDefault<PlacementInfo>();
```

I've tried replacing the line above that pulls the billingAdjusterCompany.Name with:

```
.Select(() => (claimCompany != null ? claimCompany.Name : billingAdjusterCompany.Name)).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterCompanyName)
```

and receive the following error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've also tried this line:

```
.Select(() => (claimCompany != null ? claimCompany: billingAdjusterCompany).Name).WithAlias(() => pi.BillingAdjusterCompanyName)
```

and, although I don't receive an error, the claimCompany.Id is returned instead of the claimCompany.Name

If I try just grabbing the claimCompany.Name itself like this it does return the correct data if the claimCompany isn't null, but isn't what I'm needing here.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's the ORM's job to generate JOINS from relations between entities. If you have to use so many explicit JOINs, something's wrong with the model.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but this is existing code that I took over.  I'm not looking to rewriet anything here -- just want to get that null check working.  thank you

Comment: So you don't want to be able to  use `this.Session.QueryOver<Claim>().Where(x => x.Name == claimName.ToString()).List()` instead of all this code? It would actually be easier to write raw SQL than all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Coalesce` QueryOver extension:

```
.Select(() => claimCompany.Name.Coalesce(billingAdjusterCompany.Name))
```

Please note you need NHibernate 5.3+ version to make it work.

If you use older version you have to use Criteria `coalesce` function projection:

```
.Select(Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(() => claimCompany.Name), Projections.Property(() => billingAdjusterCompany.Name))
```